# Spivak, Ch 10, Differentiation, Problem *21: How to prove that if $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

From Spivak's Calculus, chapter 10 entitled "Differentiation":

> *21:Prove that if $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists. A little experimentation should
> convince you that it is unwise to seek a a formula for $(f \circ
> > g)^{(n)}(a)$. In order to prove that $(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists you
> will therefore have to devise a reasonable assertion about $(f \circ
> > g)^{(n)}(a)$ which can be proved by induction. Try something like:
> "$(f \circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is the sum of terms each of which
> is a product of terms of the form..."

**My question concerns the following solution from the solution manual.**

The formulas for $(f \circ g)'(a)$, $(f \circ g)''(a)$, and $(f \circ g)'''(a)$ seem to show a pattern, and based on this pattern we form the following conjecture:

> If $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ exist, then also $(f \circ
>  g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists and is a sum of terms of the form
>
> $$c \cdot [g'(a)]^{m_1}...[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n} \cdot f^{(k)}(g(a))$$

where $c$ is some number; $m_1, ..., m_n$ are nonnegative integers; and $k\leq n$ is a natural number.

> To prove this assertion by induction, note that it is true for $n=1$
> (with $a=m_1=k=1$).
>
> Now suppose that for a certain $n$, this assertion is true for all
> numbers $a$ such that $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ exist.
>
> Suppose that $f^{(n+1)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n+1)}(a)$ exist.
>
> Then $g^{(k)}(x)$ must exist for all $k \leq n$ and all $x$ in some
> interval around $a$, and $f^{(k)}(y)$ must exist for all $k \leq n$
> and all $y$ in some interval around $g(a)$. Since $g$ is continuous at
> $a$, this implies that $f^{(k)}(g(x))$ exists for all $x$ in some
> interval around $a$. So the assertion is true for all these $x$, that
> is, $(f \circ g)^{(n)}$ is a sum of terms of the form
>
> $$c \cdot [g'(x)]^{m_1}...[g^{(n)}(x)]^{m_n} \cdot f^{(k)}(g(a)),\
>  m_1,...,m_n \geq 0, 1\leq k\leq n\tag{1}$$
>
> Consequently, $(f \circ g)^{(n+1)}(a)$ is a sum of terms of the form
>
> $$c \cdot m_{\alpha}
>  [g'(a)]^{m_1}...[g^{(\alpha)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha}-1}...[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}
>  \cdot f^{(k)}(g(a)),\ m_{\alpha}>0\tag{2}$$
>
> or of the form
>
> $$c \cdot [g'(a)]^{m_1+1}...[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n} \cdot
>  f^{(k+1)}(g(a))\tag{3}$$

Where did $\alpha$ come from in $(2)$ and $(3)$? More generally, what is happening in this proof starting at the line "Consequently, $(f \circ g)^{(n+1)}(a)$ is a sum..."?

$(2)$ seems to be the derivative of $(1)$, where $(1)$ has a specific element $[g^{(\alpha)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha}}$, (and I assume $\alpha<n$, though this isn't specified), and $(2)$ represents a term from the product rule applied to $(1)$ where we differentiate $[g^{(\alpha)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha}}$. However, this isn't clearly so, also because where is the term $g^{(\alpha+1)}(a)$? So actually this interpretation would seem to be incorrect.

Comment: Note that the induction can be carried out in a much more efficient manner, without having to figure out the form of $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$, so I think Spivak's hint isn't actually the most useful in this case. You simply have to argue once from the chain rule $(f\circ g)'(a)=f'(g(a))\cdot g'(a)$, so if the RHS is sufficiently differentiable, so is the LHS (assuming you have already proved an analogous result for products).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell:

In (1) the integers $m_1,...,m_n\geq 0$ (they are only non-negative, not strictly positive).

In (2) $m_\alpha$ is one of the $m$'s which is strictly positive (so generates a contribution to the derivative).

And I believe that the formula (2) should read (also consistent with your remark):

$$c \cdot m_{\alpha}
 [g'(a)]^{m_1}...[g^{(\alpha)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha}-1}[g^{(\alpha+1)}(a)]^{m_{\alpha+1}+1}
...[g^{(n)}(a)]^{m_n}
 \cdot f^{(k)}(g(a)),\ m_{\alpha}>0\tag{2}$$

Formula (3) seems ok (and there is no $\alpha$?)

Comment: There is no $\alpha$ in $(3)$.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I meant